# IdentityServer4 Persisted Grant Storage. Invalid column name 'ConsumedTime'

Tags: identityserver4

It seems the PersistedGrant table creation script defined [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/dev/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations/PersistedGrantDb.sql) is not in sync with the code of IdentityServer4.  I have applied that script to my database, and configured the persistence as described [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/ef.html), but when I test a log in, I get this error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'ConsumedTime'.
> Invalid column name 'Description'.
> Invalid column name 'SessionId'.

The stack trace shows this to be happening in the following line of code:
`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore.StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Script you have is a old one and its archived, here is link to the new script you should use:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations/PersistedGrantDb.sql